# Calling acro first use when plural is producing an 's' in the short definition that is wrong

Tags: acronyms, acro, plural

I have an acro first use that must be plural, but I am getting an erroneous "s" when I shouldn't be. I'm getting (sIMFs) when it should be (IMFs). See picture and code below. The problem only occurs on the first call and it does so for all my acronyms. Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{acro}
\DeclareAcronym{IMF}{
    short = IMF,
    long  = Intrinsic Mode Function,
    class = abbrev}

\begin{document}
\acp{IMF}
\acresetall
\ac{IMF}
\acp{IMF}
\acfp{IMF}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: To the downvote party: are you even taking the time to read the question before downvoting? If you have something to contribute please leave a comment instead.

Comment: You load a ton of packages. Probably, one of them is causing this behavior. It looks like the downvoting party (I'm not one of them and I don't see votes) is saying that they don't want to search for that package for you when it's easy to do it yourself. Just comment out one package after another. In your real document, don't load the packages to don't actually use.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately, it's not another package causing the problem. I've commented out all the other packages so only acro is being used and the problem remains. In my real document I do use all of these packages.

Comment: I've also edited the question so only the acro package is in use and better highlighted the problem. I presume therefore this is a bug with the package, unless someone can tell me otherwise. I've updated MikTex and the package to latest version.

Comment: This is of course a bug in [`acro`](https://ctan.org/pkg/acro) as is clear from the improved MWE.  It has been reported at https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/acro/issues/120/having-an-acronym-in-plural-form-the-first where a couple of work-arounds have been given.  The simplest being to explicitly set `foreign-plural={}` for any affected acronyms.

Comment: loading acro with the following option worked for me `\usepackage[display-foreign=false]{acro}`

Answer (score 5):

[This issue](https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/acro/issues/120) [is fixed](https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/acro/commits/284d09b5f358) in the current version 2.10 of `acro`.

Comment: what about overleaf? we cannot controll the package version, right?

Comment: @Leos313 this is also fixed on Overleaf, I just checked with the MWE from the OP: https://www.overleaf.com/read/tcqsrpdhykjc

Comment: I cannot share here the image. However, if I have the same bug, I am doing something wrong. Question: is there a way of checking which version I am using of the package?

Comment: @Leos313 yes, search the log file. The information is in there somewhere