# Extra "s" in acro with plural in first use

Tags: acro, plural

I really hope I am posting in the right forum and location. My apologies if it is incorrect.

Essentially, I have a strange problem that occurs when the first use of an acronym happens to be in plural form. In that case, an 's' is appended *in front of* the short form as well as in the end. This happens not only for this particular one, but also several other acronyms I use, and I have not managed to work around it by using 'short-plural', 'short-plural-form', 'long-plural', or 'long-plural-form'.

Any help is appreciated.
See below for an MWE and the result I get from that exact code.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{acro}
\DeclareAcronym{bc}{short =BC, long = boundary condition}
\begin{document}
Then, \acp{bc} are applied.
\end{document}
```

[image: extra-'s']

Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I can't confirm this. If I compile your MWE, I get the expected output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABPcA.png

Comment: Related/possible duplicate: [Calling acro first use when plural is producing an 's' in the short definition that is wrong](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/499134/134144)

Comment: To summarize: the observed behaviour is a bug that was resolved (see also https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/acro/issues/120/having-an-acronym-in-plural-form-the-first). After updating to version `2.10` you should get you the desired result.

Comment: Thank you very much! I had not found this during my searches, maybe because the first time I looked was quite a while ago and I have just been postponing dealing with this problem since then. The workaround does the trick. I will also try updating.